# How to combine two columns into one and ignore null values - Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, join, concatenation, trim

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer and i have the following select:

```
SELECT a1.numero_brevetto,
         a1.titolo,
         a2.descrizione,
         a1.data_scadenza_brevetto,
         listagg(a3.organizzazione, ', ') within group (order by a3.organizzazione) organizzazione_1,
         listagg(a4.ragione_sociale, ', ' ) within group (order by a4.ragione_sociale) organizzazione_2
    FROM b_brevetto a1
         FULL OUTER JOIN b_tipo_brevetto a2
            ON a1.tipo_brevetto = a2.tipo_brevetto
         LEFT JOIN b_brevetto_titolari a3
            ON a1.codice_brevetto = a3.codice_brevetto
         LEFT JOIN b_ditta a4
            on a3.codice_ditta=a4.codice_ditta
   WHERE a3.corrente = 1 AND a1.numero_brevetto = 'BREVETTO10000'
GROUP by a1.numero_brevetto,
         a1.titolo,
         a2.descrizione,
         a1.data_scadenza_brevetto          
ORDER BY a1.numero_brevetto
```

The output is:

```
NUMERO_BREVETTO        TITOLO                        DESCRIZIONE                   DATA_SCAD       ORGANIZZAZIONE_1                       ORGANIZZAZIONE_2                                                                                                                                                                                         
---------------------- ----------------------------- ----------------------------- --------------- -------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------
BREVETTO10000          asdsad                        Brevetto italiano             18-FEB-39       (null)                                 BAYER S.P.A.
```

Starting from the previous select, I want to concatenate the values of the column Organizzazione_1 with the values of Organizzazione_2. i want to obtain the following output:

```
NUMERO_BREVETTO        TITOLO                        DESCRIZIONE                   DATA_SCAD       ORGANIZZAZIONE_1_ORGANIZZAZIONE_2                                                                                                                                                                                                               
---------------------- ----------------------------- ----------------------------- --------------- -------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------
BREVETTO10000          asdsad                        Brevetto italiano             18-FEB-39       BAYER S.P.A.
```

I tried with the CONCAT function:

```
SELECT a1.numero_brevetto,
         a1.titolo,
         a2.descrizione,
         a1.data_scadenza_brevetto,
         concat(concat(listagg(a3.organizzazione, ', ') within group (order by a3.organizzazione), ', '),
         listagg(a4.ragione_sociale, ', ' ) within group (order by a4.ragione_sociale)) titolari
    FROM b_brevetto a1
         FULL OUTER JOIN b_tipo_brevetto a2
            ON a1.tipo_brevetto = a2.tipo_brevetto
         LEFT JOIN b_brevetto_titolari a3
            ON a1.codice_brevetto = a3.codice_brevetto
         LEFT JOIN b_ditta a4
            on a3.codice_ditta=a4.codice_ditta
   WHERE a3.corrente = 1 AND a1.numero_brevetto = 'BREVETTO10000'
GROUP by a1.numero_brevetto,
         a1.titolo,
         a2.descrizione,
         a1.data_scadenza_brevetto          
ORDER BY a1.numero_brevetto
```

but i have this output:

```
NUMERO_BREVETTO        TITOLO                        DESCRIZIONE                   DATA_SCAD       ORGANIZZAZIONE_1_ORGANIZZAZIONE_2                                                                                                                                                                                                               
---------------------- ----------------------------- ----------------------------- --------------- -------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------
BREVETTO10000          asdsad                        Brevetto italiano             18-FEB-39       , BAYER S.P.A.
```

I wuold like to find a way to remove the extra comma near "BAYER S.P.A." when the column ORGANIZZAZIONE_1 has NULL value (how in this case). Moreover i wuold also remove the extra comma if column_ORGANIZZAZIONE_1 has had NOT NULL values and column ORGANIZZAZIONE_" all NULL VALUE, for example:

```
NUMERO_BREVETTO        TITOLO                        DESCRIZIONE                   DATA_SCAD       ORGANIZZAZIONE_1                       ORGANIZZAZIONE_2                                                                                                                                                                                         
---------------------- ----------------------------- ----------------------------- --------------- -------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------
BREVETTO20000          asdsad                        Brevetto italiano             18-FEB-59       PFIZER S.P.A.                         (null)
```

I want to have:

```
NUMERO_BREVETTO        TITOLO                        DESCRIZIONE                   DATA_SCAD       ORGANIZZAZIONE_1_ORGANIZZAZIONE_2                                                                                                                                                                                                               
---------------------- ----------------------------- ----------------------------- --------------- -------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------
BREVETTO10000          asdsad                        Brevetto italiano             18-FEB-39       PFIZER S.P.A.
```

Finally i want to mantain the comma in the case both column have values:

```
NUMERO_BREVETTO        TITOLO                        DESCRIZIONE                   DATA_SCAD       ORGANIZZAZIONE_1                       ORGANIZZAZIONE_2                                                                                                                                                                                         
---------------------- ----------------------------- ----------------------------- --------------- -------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------
BREVETTO10000          asdsad                        Brevetto italiano             18-FEB-39       PFIZER S.P.A.                          BAYER S.P.A., TEVA S.P.A.
```

I want to have:

```
NUMERO_BREVETTO        TITOLO                        DESCRIZIONE                   DATA_SCAD       ORGANIZZAZIONE_1_ORGANIZZAZIONE_2                                                                                                                                                                                                               
---------------------- ----------------------------- ----------------------------- --------------- -------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------
BREVETTO10000          asdsad                        Brevetto italiano             18-FEB-39       PFIZER S.P.A., BAYER S.P.A., TEVA S.P.A.
```

Pls help me
P.S: Sorry for my english

Comment: To handle null you need a [`coalesce`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617) function. Then just [`trim`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions207.htm#SQLRF06149) that extra spaces and commas.

Comment: Tip: `a1`, `a2` etc are poor table aliases. Chose something that makes sense, e.g. `d` for `b_ditta`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is multiple ways to do this:

```
case when listagg(a3.organizzazione, ', ') within group (order by a3.organizzazione) is not null 
     then  listagg(a3.organizzazione, ', ') within group (order by a3.organizzazione) || ',' 
end
||
listagg(a4.ragione_sociale, ', ' ) within group (order by a4.ragione_sociale)
```

or simplest way is to use the `trim` as follows:

```
trim(both ',' from
listagg(a3.organizzazione, ', ') within group (order by a3.organizzazione)
|| ','
|| listagg(a4.ragione_sociale, ', ' ) within group (order by a4.ragione_sociale)
)
```

Comment: The trim function with the || operator were very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine two nvl2 function like below.

```sql
SELECT a1.numero_brevetto,
         a1.titolo,
         a2.descrizione,
         a1.data_scadenza_brevetto,
         nvl2(listagg(a3.organizzazione, ', ') within group (order by a3.organizzazione)
         ,  nvl2(listagg(a4.ragione_sociale, ', ' ) within group (order by a4.ragione_sociale)
                ,   listagg(a3.organizzazione, ', ') within group (order by a3.organizzazione)
                    ||', '||listagg(a4.ragione_sociale, ', ' ) within group (order by a4.ragione_sociale)
                ,   listagg(a3.organizzazione, ', ') within group (order by a3.organizzazione)
            )
         ,  listagg(a4.ragione_sociale, ', ' ) within group (order by a4.ragione_sociale)
         ) organizzazione_1_organizzazione_2
    FROM b_brevetto a1
         FULL OUTER JOIN b_tipo_brevetto a2
            ON a1.tipo_brevetto = a2.tipo_brevetto
         LEFT JOIN b_brevetto_titolari a3
            ON a1.codice_brevetto = a3.codice_brevetto
         LEFT JOIN b_ditta a4
            on a3.codice_ditta=a4.codice_ditta
   WHERE a3.corrente = 1 AND a1.numero_brevetto = 'BREVETTO10000'
GROUP by a1.numero_brevetto,
         a1.titolo,
         a2.descrizione,
         a1.data_scadenza_brevetto          
ORDER BY a1.numero_brevetto
;
```